# The sum of the Leibniz-like series of the form $\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n(n+1)/2} a_n\;$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

I'm having problems to evaluate sums using Wolfram or online sites like that for sums of the form

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}2} a_n$$

with $\;a_n\;$ some sequence, since Wolfram keeps on interpretating $\;(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}2}=i^{n(n+1)}\;$ , which of couse is absurd as $\;\frac{n(n+1)}2\;$ is always a natural number...!

My question is twofold: is there any way to write the above expression to go around the above interpretation of Wolfram? And also: is there any other good resource online to evaluate infinite series besides Wolfram?

I need the above for some interactive resources for mathematics classes (more precisely: Advanced Calculus and/or Harmonic Analysis), either online (zoom) or frontal. If it helps I get some of those series as Fourier series after evaluating at some point using Dirichlet theorem.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would this be absurd? $(-1)^k=i^{2k}$ for any integer $k$: take $k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, no?

Comment: @Mindlack Because (1) I am trying to keep things educationally basic as much as I can, and (2) the final output Wolfram gives is a complex non-real number, which means its algorithm is doing something wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do separately the even and odd terms.  $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{(2k+1)(2k+2)/2} a_{2k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} a_{2k+1}\\\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{(2k)(2k+1)/2} a_{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k} a_{2k}$$

Comment: I think this method  is, in general, forbidden...and wrong: one cannot, in general, rearrange terms of a conditionally convergent series, unless it is proved that one can in a specific manner... In my personal case it seesm t obe possible (I still need to prove it), in general though it can't be done. Anyway, my question was not how to prove but how to input in Wolfram or in any other online resource. Thanks.